# undefined reference to `X<int>::X(int)'

Tags: c++, linker-errors

in header `testh.h`, i have the following

```
#include<stdlib.h>
template<typename T>
class X {
    public:
    T x;
    X(T i);
    void assign(T *i); 
    
};
```

the file `obj.cpp`, has the following

```
#include<testh.h>

template<typename T> 
X<T>::X(T i) {
    //...
}
```

(using `obj.cpp` as object files(`.o`) for linking)

in the main call in file `test.cpp`, has the following

```
#include<testh.h>

int main() {
    X<int> x(20);
    return 0;
}
```

but calling the constructor of `X` with template[T=int], get the linker error

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccHiPTCC.o: in function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `X<int>::X(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

is there a get around for defining class members in a separate file while using templates?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) cover your question?

Comment: `obj.cpp` did not instantiate `X<int>::int(int)`.  Which is why template implementations usually are in the header files and not in the cpp files.